# Kill dask worker when no result/fail

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am running a dask.distributed Client that gets data from an API with several parameters, parses results and joins/aggregates on each result. This is done with client.map()

Sometimes the API call gives an empty string because the specific combination of input parameters doesn't exist. It doesn't make sense to continue with computations and I would like to just kill that worker (without passing on e.g. a None).

**How do I tell Dask to kill a worker if its result is None/error and exclude that future from the following operations?**

Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Added a minimal working example to show the logic: the first map produces a lot of "useless" workers that I would like to kill.
Please notice that this is **not my actual use case**, I am querying an Influx database via http requests but the general structure of the code is the same. *I am open to any comments on how to do that faster/more efficiently*.

´´´´python

```
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster, as_completed
import dask.dataframe as dd


def fetch_html(pair):
    req_string = 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/order_book/{currency_pair}/'
    response = requests.get(req_string.format(currency_pair=pair))
    try:
        result = response.json()
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: {}\nMessage: {}'.format(e,response.reason))
        return None


def parse_result(result):
    if result:
        data = {}
        data['prices'] = [e[0] for e in result['bids']]
        data['vols'] = [e[1] for e in result['bids']]
        data['index'] = [result['timestamp'] for i in data['prices']]
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).set_index('index')
        return df
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame()


def other_calcs(result):
    if not result.empty:
        # something
        return result
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame()


def aggregator(res1, res2):
    if (not res1.empty) and (not res2.empty):
        # something
        return res1
    elif not res2.empty:
        # something
        return res2
    elif not res1.empty:
        return res1
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame()


if __name__=='__main__':
    pairs = [
        # legit params (100s of these):
        'btcusd',
        'btceur',
        'btcgbp',
        'bateur',
        'batbtc',
        'umausd',
        'xrpusdt',
        'eurteur',
        'eurtusd',
        'manausd',
        'sandeur',
        'storjusd',
        'storjeur',
        'adausd',
        'adaeur',
        # bad params resulting in error / empty result (100s of these)
        'foobar',
        'foobaz',
        'foousd',
        'barbaz',
        'bazbar',
             ]

    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=16, threads_per_worker=1)
    client = Client(cluster)
    futures_list = client.map(fetch_html, pairs)
    futures_list = client.map(parse_result, futures_list)
    futures_list = client.map(other_calcs, futures_list) 
    seq = as_completed(futures_list)
    while seq.count() > 1:
        f1 = next(seq)
        f2 = next(seq)
        new = client.submit(aggregator, f1, f2, priority=1)
        seq.add(new)
    final = next(seq)
    final = final.result()
    print(final.head())
```

´´´´

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you would like to kill a worker? Wouldn't it be more efficient to let the worker proceed to the next task?

Comment: agreed. also, yes, code - ideally an [mre] would be helpful. if you're looking for a generic answer that can be applied to a simple case, then it would be great if you could draft one up for us so we're all looking at the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: I will provide minimal code thanks! I need to kill workers because I am making hundreds of http requests and then doing mapping on these (parsing etc.). If a http request is empty I don't want to carry on the future (since it will use resources, especially since I don't have so many cores), but rather kill it (i.e. having less futures to map on the following steps).

Comment: @MichaelDelgado
I posted a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev I posted a minimal reproducible example